# How to call a swift function from TypeScript

Tags: swift, typescript

I am writing a function on a button click in my TypeScript file.

```
<button (click)="invokeMessage()">Submit</button>

invokeMessage() {
  const text = 'Hello iOS!';
  this.swiftMethod(text);
}

swiftMethod(text: string) { }
```

I need to call this function "swiftMethod()" in swift. But not getting a callback when using above code.

However I am able to achieve this through JavaScript:

```
<html>
    <title>
        my title
    </title>
    <head>
        <script>
            function invokeMessage() {
                var inputName = document.getElementById('name').value
                swiftMethod(inputName)
            }    
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick='invokeMessage()'>Submit</button>
        <input type='text' name='firstname' id='name' value='Jamie'><br>
    </body>
</html>
```

Swift Code:

```
extension ViewController: UIWebViewDelegate {

  func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {

    print("text")        

    let ctx = webView.value(forKeyPath: "documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext") as! JSContext        

    let swiftMethod: @convention(block) (String) -> () = { email in

      print("Got Callback email = \(email) ")

    }        

    ctx.setObject(unsafeBitCast(swiftMethod, to: AnyObject.self), forKeyedSubscript: "swiftMethod" as (NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol)?)

  }

}
```

How to write my function in TypeScript?

Comment: Hey are doing it for react-native or some hybrid app ?

Comment: @Naresh Hi, actually I have a survey inside my web app. My mobile team(Android, iOS) gets to open the survey through a link getting from back end. When they open the link and submit survey, they need to trigger something. And that's why need to implement what I mentioned above.

Comment: Hey you can't achieve this but your mobile team can observe the change in URL while submitting the SURVEY to update the mobile app. And this is the only way to achieve this.

Comment: I feel there is some way possible, as I am able to achieve the same in Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad to get some useful posts/links which helps me to answer my question.

After iOS 8, Apple recommends using `WKWebView` over `UIWebView` (I am making use of `UIWebView` 
 above).

I got [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-build-cross-origin-communication-bridges-in-ios-and-andriod-7baef82b3f02/) post which explains how a communication is possible in between iOS/Android and JavaScript.

Also got [this](https://github.com/ClintJang/sample-swift-wkwebview-javascript-bridge-and-scheme/blob/master/README-en.md) one which explains how to bridge `JavaScript` and `WKWebView` in different ways.

Finally about my code, after taking reference from above, I wrote the following TypeScript function:

```
<button (click)="invokeMessage()">Submit</button>

invokeMessage() {
  try {
      (window as any).webkit.messageHandlers.callbackHandler.postMessage('testValue');
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```